# Combine WLAN with LAN

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, lan

I have D-link DSL 2750U wireless router. My PC and notebook are connected to router by Wi-Fi. They can share files or ping each other. I have a network storage unit plugged into router by an ethernet cable. Any of the computers cannot reach that storage unit or ping it. I guess my router isolates LAN network from WLAN network. Is there a way to combine them and get the router treat all devices connected to router in a single network? Thanks.

Comment: Some routers have two VLANs that are built in; Main Wireless and Guest Wireless. Make sure that you're not connecting through the guest wireless.

Comment: Isolation between LAN and WLAN is not standard behaviour for these types of router, but might be a setting you may have inadvertently enabled.  If you plug another device into the LAN ports, are you able to connect to the NAS from it?

Answer (score 5):

Disable "Enable MultiAP Isolation" setting under wireless network settings.

That worked for me on D-link DSL 2750U.

Comment: I don't have that option in my panel. Please see the screenshot here: http://f.cl.ly/items/2Z1q450P0B342h123p1x/Image%202014-04-03%20at%202.16.45%20AM.png

Comment: It is located at Setup -> wireless -> basic -> "Enable MultiAP Isolation"

Comment: It worked for me too.

Answer (score 0):

your router shouldn't 'isolate' LAN from WLAN. As kobaltz said, make sure your not connected to the guest wireless, then try to connect to the NAS (Network Attached Storage) again. If not, check the IP of the NAS itself. If it starts with `169.254.X.X`, you got a configuration error. It should start with `192.168.X.X`. Try rebooting the NAS and router. Also, check your MAC address filtering, make sure the router is not blocking the NAS's MAC address.

If these solutions don't work, leave a comment and I'll look further into it. Good luck!

Comment: NAS already has 192.168.1.X IP address and I have no active MAC address filtering. I am not connecting to Guest Network as I am using WEP passphrase to connect that I created on router configuration panel. So I guess it must be something else.

Comment: how are you connecting to NAS? make sure to connect using this syntax:
`\\domain\default_path` (for windows, not sure about Mac, will look into that) e.g. if the name of the NAS is myNetStorage, and you want the "home" folder to be the "shares" folder, then connect using `\\myNetStorage\shares\` (you can just enter this into windows explorer to see if it works, if it does then add it as network drive). My brain is exhausted from big day, so sorry if it's confusing. In the meantime I need sleep

Comment: [Here's](http://osxdaily.com/2010/09/20/map-a-network-drive-on-a-mac/) how you can map the NAS drive(s) on MAC

If this doesn't help, or that's not the problem, just drop a comment with any details you may have figured out since you posted the question

Comment: as i said, i can't even ping the ip, i get "host is not reachable" response. how can i map a drive i can't even ping?

Comment: any more ideas?

Comment: oh right. sorry i took so long to respond. anyways, perhaps its firwall? other than that, i don't know sorry. can't think of anything else. If i come up with anything though, I'll drop a comment for you.